# How to get the value of the 3rd column using regex

Tags: regex, file, logging, matching

I have a log like this:

> [2015-09-03 04:54:23,755] [Log Name] [INFO ] [test.audit1] [AUD5454] [default/test1] logged out.
>
> [2015-09-01 01:33:45,851] [Log Name] [Critical ] [test.audit2] [AUD53501] [default/test2] logged in.

I need to get the 3rd column value between [], i tried with this regex:

```
(?<=\[)[^\]]+
```

but it only give me the value between []

> [INFO ] => INFO
>
> [Critical ] => Critical

... I need those values INFO & Critical

Another question how to get the value after [default/test2] & [default/test1]

> logged out.
>
> logged in.

Comment: Try [`^(?:\s*\[[^]]*\]){2}\s*\[([^]]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/tX3mX8/1). The value will be in Group 1. Please let know if it works for you.

Comment: It worked on that example in that website & the site but doesn't work with my solution i think thats becuase the solution adding another data to the log,

Comment: that the log from my solution:

https://regex101.com/r/iW7xC2/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iW7xC2/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\s*\[[^\]]*\]){2}\s*\[([^\]]*)\](?:\s*\[[^\]]*\])*\s*(.*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xH0wU8/2)

The values you need are in Group 1 and 2.

Comment: It worked on that example in that website & the site but doesn't work with my solution i think thats becuase the solution adding another data to the log,

Comment: that the log from my solution: regex101.com/r/iW7xC2/1

Comment: I have updated the answer. Note that multiline mode is used, but I do not know where you are using the regex. I can adjust it if you let me know it.

Comment: I'm using it in Qradar SIEM Solution, i will test the new answer

Comment: You might try `(?m)(?:\s*\[[^]]*\]){2}\s*\[([^]]*)\](?:\s*\[[^]]*\])*\s*(.*?)\s*$` or `(?:\s*\[[^]]*\]){2}\s*\[([^]]*)\](?:\s*\[[^]]*\])*\s*(.*?)\s*(?:\n|$)`.

Comment: Your solution is the right answer for that log but it doesn't work with Qradar :( i don't know why!

Comment: I have just read that Qradar uses ICU regex flavor, but perhaps, it has its own limitations. Try `(?:\s*\[[^\]]*\]){2}\s*\[([^\]]*)\](?:\s*\[[^\]]*\])*\s*(.*)`, but I have no clue if you have access to capturing groups. If there are named captures (as in Grok) try `(?:\s*\[[^\]]*\]){2}\s*\[(?<thirdField>[^\]]*)\](?:\s*\[[^\]]*\])*\s*(?<comment>.*)`. I also escaped squre brackets in character classes now.

Comment: You saved me :D Worked very good to select the 3rd column but the string logged out. didn't worked for it.

Thank you alot

Comment: This is to get only the last part of the log
(?:\s*\[[^\]]*\])(?:\s*\[[^\]]*\])*\s*(.*)

Comment: Use `\`` to enclose the `\``code`\`` (`code`) or it is difficult to read and then reuse. So, it works now?

Comment: Simplify it to `(?:\[([^\]]*)\]\s*){3}(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s*)*(.*)` by taking advantage of the fact that only the last repetition is captured. https://regex101.com/r/xH0wU8/3

Comment: Ha! Good trick, never thought about using it like that to shorten regexps.

Comment: `(?:\s*[[^]]*])(?:\s*[[^]]*])*\s*(.*)`  Great Thanks guys for your help, i'm really appreciate that